# when i installing the "cronie" the system mentioned me that ths cronie require the "dailyjobs"

Tags: linux, rpm, yum

when i installing the "cronie" the system mentioned me that ths cronie require the "dailyjobs" like the following shows:

> Error: Package: cronie-1.4.4-7.2.alios6.x86_64 
>              Requires: dailyjobs

I have searched it online but no tip works.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
# dnf whatprovides dailyjobs
Last metadata expiration check performed 5:25:06 ago on Wed Aug 19 08:01:36 2015.
cronie-anacron-1.4.12-5.fc22.x86_64 : Utility for running regular jobs
Repo        : @System

cronie-anacron-1.4.12-5.fc22.x86_64 : Utility for running regular jobs
Repo        : fedora

cronie-noanacron-1.4.12-5.fc22.x86_64 : Utility for running simple regular jobs in old cron style
Repo        : fedora

# rpm -q --provides cronie-anacron
anacron = 2.4
config(cronie-anacron) = 1.4.12-5.fc22
cronie-anacron = 1.4.12-5.fc22
cronie-anacron(x86-64) = 1.4.12-5.fc22
dailyjobs
```

Comment: thanks but i still don't know how to fix it,i'm a newbie of this .Can you specify it more clearley? please

Answer (score 0):

Install cronie and cronie-anacron at same time.

`rpm -i cronie-xxxx.rpm cronie-anacron-xxxx.rpm`